# How do I configure an AD DC to respond to LDAP binds on ldaps://?

Tags: domain-name-system, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

I am working with a Windows Server 2012 R2 DC which is the acting LDAP authentication server for the domain.

From both `ldp.exe` on the same machine and `php5-ldap` on a separate Ubuntu box on the network, I'm able to make an LDAP over SSL bind on the URI `myserver.example.com` on port 636, but not on the URI `ldaps://myserver.example.com` (with or without appended `:636`).

This is causing problems for a PHP authentication module I'm using elsewhere and, while I'm able to go into the module and manually hack at it to use the URI which works, I'd rather know why adding the URI prefix `ldaps://` seems to break things.

This same DC is also a DNS provider for the network. I've manually added an `A` record to point `myserver.example.com` at its own IP address. I'm thinking that perhaps I need to add additional (possibly `SRV`) records to support binding on `ldaps://myserver.example.com`, but I don't know enough about managing DNS on Windows Server to know where to put these (if indeed I need them at all!)

So to summarise: **why is it that I can perform an LDAP over SSL bind on the URI `myserver.example.com`, but not on either `ldaps://myserver.example.com` or `ldaps://myserver.example.com:636`, and how can I change this behaviour?**